# How to handle multiple OR condition in IF

Tags: c++, logic, conditional-statements

```
bool A=false;
bool B=true;

if(!A || !B)
{
.....
}
```

In this condition when `A` is true, it didn't checks the `B` but I want to check B instead of A .

In this condition I want to execute if any one is true(A or B), But If A is true I want to check B also. is there any other logic to resolve this apart from using different if conditions?

Comment: `if(A || B)` ??

Comment: `But If A is true I want to check B` You mean `if ( A && B )` or `if ( A && !B )`. However, I am not sure, it's unclear what you 're trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "But If A is true I want to check B also" Could you make a truth table of all results?

Comment: You know what `OR` is? Whenever a `TRUE` is reached, the check stops...

Comment: The value of B is short circuited if and only if it has no impact on the condition. It is therefore meaningless to evaluate, except if B itself has any side effects (that is, if B is not a boolean but an expression that can have an impact on the program state).

Comment: "check B" does not make any sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. I found solution for this logic, `if(!(A || B))` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may turn off short-circut evaluation in your compiler. If you work with your own types, you may overload `||` and `&&`. Overloaded logical operators are not short-circuted.

Both things are **really bad**. Programmers expect logical operators to behave in certain way and are very likely to get super confused with this unexpected behavior. You should stick to short-circuting.